# config a cisco router through paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to config a cisco router through paramiko.
First I ssh to router and then run commands. But when I connect to router I can not go to configuer mode.
I mean the router connect in user mode and running the  `en`  or `conf t` do not work!

```
conn = paramiko.SSHClient()
conn.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
conn.connect("20.0.0.1", 22, "cisco", "123")
stdin, stdout, stderr = conn.exec_command('show ip int br')
status = stdout.channel.exit_status_ready()
if status==0:
 mystring = stdout.read()
 print mystring
```

The status is 0, but mystring is an empty string.(result is:[])

I'm on Fedora 20.

Thanks

Comment: what about `stderr`? what about the stdout and stderr  of `en` ?

Comment: Actually I,m new in python. I find this code by searching.Sorry, I don't understand your qestion!

Comment: after connect try: `print conn.get_transport().is_active()` so: you got a success connection ?

Comment: thanks for your reply. The results of running `print conn.get_transport().is_active()` is **true**.

Comment: I found exec_command is a non-blocking call. So I edit my code, but I don,t have any result!

Answer (score 2):

Note: Be sure You enable the ssh on your cisco switch. I used Cisco VIRL ISO. Also change username and password as per your ssh.

```
import paramiko
import time
def attempt():

    IP = "192.168.0.52"
    USER = "cisco"
    Password = "cisco"
    PORT=22
      
    try:

        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        #ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
 
        try:
            ssh.connect(IP , port=PORT, username=USER, password=Password)
            print ("Connected successfully.")

            connection = ssh.invoke_shell()
            connection.send("enable\n")
            time.sleep(.5)
            connection.send("cisco\n")
            time.sleep(.5)
           #connection.send("conf t\n")
            connection.send("show ip int brief\n")
            #connection.send("int loop 2\n")
           #connection.send("ip address 2.3.1.1 255.255.255.255\n")
            
            time.sleep(.5)
            router_output = connection.recv(65535)
            time.sleep(.5)
            print("\n\n")
            print(str(router_output) + "\n")
            time.sleep(.5)

            connection.send("end\n")

        except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
            print ("Incorrect password: "+Password)

        except socket.erro:
            print ("Socket Error")
    except:
        print("Something Went Wrong")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your above command works for me on a Cisco 881 (i.e. 'show ip int br' runs correctly and the output is played.

If I add a second command, like 'conf t' or 'enable' it fails. This is because exec_command on Cisco only allows a single command. You need to run the .invoke_shell() method to execute multiple commands.

Here is an example:

```
import paramiko
from getpass import getpass
import time

ip = raw_input("Please enter your IP address: ")
username = raw_input("Please enter your username: ")
password = getpass()

remote_conn_pre=paramiko.SSHClient()
remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, port=22, username=username,  
                        password=password,
                        look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)

remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
output = remote_conn.recv(65535)
print output

remote_conn.send("show ip int brief\n")
time.sleep(.5)
output = remote_conn.recv(65535)
print output

remote_conn.send("conf t\n")
time.sleep(.5)
output = remote_conn.recv(65535)
print output

remote_conn.send("end\n")
time.sleep(.5)
output = remote_conn.recv(65535)
print output
```

You might also want to check out this library that I have been working on. It simplifies some of these mechanics:

https://pynet.twb-tech.com/blog/automation/netmiko.html